# Open Connection to SQL Compact File, with other Extension than .sdf

Tags: sql-server-ce, database-connection

I just can't open this connection if the file extension is different to `.sdf`.

Is there a workaround? Please do not suggest temporarily changing the file extension.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean from code, or also from the server view in Visual Studio?